# How should I send my token inside my user entity?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jwt, typeorm

Well, I'm making a "forgot password" controller, in which the user sends the email and receives in his mailbox a token that expires in two hours so that he can use it to create a new password, but my question is, avoid with that this user generates several tokens while he already has one, so I intend to create a boolean column "isForgotPasswordToken" in my user entity, which if it is true means that a token has already been generated for that user. My real question is, how can I send this boolean inside the entity as false and how can I send this token inside the entity, what would be a good practice for that? Or would it be a best practice to create an entity just for that and somehow bind to the user id?

User entity

```
import { BeforeInsert, BeforeUpdate, Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

@Entity('users')
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column()
    username: string;

    @Column()
    email: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;

    @BeforeInsert()
    @BeforeUpdate()
    hashPassword() {
        this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, 8);
    }
}
```

ForgotPasswordController

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { User } from "../entities/User";
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import { AppDataSource } from "../database/Config";
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

class forgotPasswordController {
    async authenticate(req: Request, res: Response) {
        const { email } = req.body;
        const secret = process.env.JWT_SEC as string;

        try {
            const user = await AppDataSource.manager.findOneBy(User, {
                email: email
            });

            if (!user) {
                return res.status(401).json('Email not registered!');
            };

            const token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, secret, {
                expiresIn: process.env.EXPIRES_LOGIN,
            });

            if (!token) {
                return res.status(401).json('Expired token, please try again.')
            }


        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json(err);
        }

    }
}

export default new forgotPasswordController();
```

Comment: Do you really need to ensure that only one token is issued ? Because its seems than you need to add a lot of extra logic to make this works which isn't the best. 

Then what happens if a token has already been issued but something went wrong while sending the mail and you user never received it ? 

If nothing critical prevent you from letting the user generate as much token as he wants I believe you shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

You can sign the jwt token with your secret and the user password hash.
So if a user change the password with one of the tokens, every other token of the user gets invalid because the password hash changes.
Thats because you cant verify the old jwt with the new secret.

My idea would be implemented roughly as:

```
const token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, secret + "_" + user.passhash, {
    expiresIn: process.env.EXPIRES_LOGIN,
});
```

In this way, the user can be able to send multiple emails with valid tokens.
But after the first time the user change the password all other tokens get invalid.

It is important to note that when the user changes the password, the password (and password-hash) must be different from the previous one.